# Primefaces RequestContext scrollTo does not work

Tags: jsf, primefaces, requestcontext

**Primefaces v3.5**

Trying to use `RequestContext.getContext().scrollTo("")` to scroll to my  form programmatically at the end of an ajax request.

*XHTML snippets:*

```
<h:form id="genericMessagesForm">
                    <p:messages id="genericMessages" />
                </h:form>
<p:commandButton id="testButton" 
            value="Test" process="#{cc.attrs.itemName}Final, @this"
                actionListener="#{myBean.methodCalledByAjax()}" />
```

*Bean:*

```
public void methodCalledByAjax() {
    List<String> updateTargets = new ArrayList<String>();
                updateTargets.add("currentRecordForm");
                updateTargets.add("genericMessagesForm");
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(updateTargets);
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().scrollTo("genericMessagesForm");
}
```

Update **does** work.

ScrollTo **does NOT** work (same ID!).

No server errors thrown.

No javascript console errors thrown.

**Browsers tried:** Firefox (latest), Chrome (latest), IE8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you look in the documentation? Here's a cite from the [`RequestContext#scrollTo()` javadoc](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.5/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html#scrollTo%28java.lang.String%29):

> ### scrollTo
>
> `public abstract void scrollTo(String clientId)`
>
> Scroll to a component after ajax request is completed.
>
> #### Parameters:
>
> `clientId` - Client side identifier of the component.

Look, it says client ID, not component ID. It makes also sense, the scrolling job is ultimately done by JavaScript via `document.getElementById()` and friends. That works only with a client ID.

For starters who haven't memorized the whole [`NamingContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) thing, an easy way to figure the right client ID is by looking at the JSF-generated HTML output via rightclick, *View Source* in webbrowser.

For a

```
<h:form id="genericMessagesForm">
    <p:messages id="genericMessages" />
</h:form>
```

that's thus something like

```
<form id="genericMessagesForm" ...>
    <div id="genericMessagesForm:genericMessages" ...>
        ...
    </div>
</form>
```

So, fix the call accordingly:

```
requestContext.scrollTo("genericMessagesForm:genericMessages");
```

By the way, if the form contains solely the `<p:messages>`, then you can alternatively also just get rid of the whole form altogether. The `<p:messages>` is not an [`EditableValueHolder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/EditableValueHolder.html) nor [`ActionSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/ActionSource.html) component and does therefore not require to be placed in an [`UIForm`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIForm.html) component. This way you can keep using your initial attempt.

#### See also:

- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier/8644762#8644762)

Comment: D'oh, of course! Thanks again BalusC and also for the explanation about not needing the form :-)