# TreeTable scroll to selected item

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my project I'm using [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org/) components to define GUI. I'm using [`TreeTable`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/treetable/scroll.xhtml) component, where its items can be selected and the body is scrollable.

Next to the table, I have a `CommandButton`, that adds the new item to the table. This item is then created, `TreeTable` is updated via ajax and the new item is selected. Problem I'm trying to solve is how to scroll to the new item. I have item's row key, so I can reconstruct its id, so I've tried to add this to my `CommandButton`:

`oncomplete="PrimeFaces.focus('form1:mainTreeTable_node_0_0_3_1');"`, where 0_0_3_1 is the row key. This only focuses the row, but does not scroll the body of the table to it. Is there a way how to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, it is all html, css and javascript. Where they are in this case all supported by jquery.

See also:

- [Scroll to top on messages rendered in PrimeFaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22804833/scroll-to-top-on-messages-rendered-in-primefaces)
- http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1795
- [Primefaces RequestContext scrollTo does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748678/primefaces-requestcontext-scrollto-does-not-work)

Comment: Thanks, you kicked me in the right direction! `RequestContext scrollTo` method works only with page body (in PF 4.0), but I was able to implement my own similar method that handles scroll in TreeTable.